# How can I get reference to anonymous inner class method 'helloWorld' from outside using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, inner-classes

Below is my sample class. As you can see, I have defined a class `InnerClass` and in the main method created an instance of it. But instead of normal declaration, I declared a anonymous innerclass of it with a method that is not there in the base class.

Now I know that if I will declare `helloWorld()` inside InnerClass, then I can access this method on the instance created through anonymous inner class.

But I want to know, if it is possible to call this method without declaring in base class in my code. I tried exploring reflection API but didn't have any luck

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class InnerClass {
int i = 10;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    InnerClass inner = new InnerClass() {
        void helloWorld() {
            System.out.println("Hello");
            System.out.println(this.getClass().getEnclosingMethod());
        }
    };
    System.out.println(inner.getClass().getEnclosingMethod());
    Method[] method = inner.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();

    // Call helloworld method here

    for (Method me : method) {
        System.out.println(me.getName());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getDeclaredMethod` retrieves the method which can be executed with `invoke`:

```
Method method = inner.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("helloWorld");
method.invoke(inner);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code uses `getDeclaredMethod` to find the `Method` you want, and then calls `invoke` to invoke it.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class InnerClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InnerClass inner = new InnerClass() {
            void helloWorld() {
                System.out.println("Hello");
                System.out.println(this.getClass().getEnclosingMethod());
            }
        };

        try {
            Method m = inner.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("helloWorld");
            m.invoke(inner);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
public static void InnerClass.main(java.lang.String[])
```